# WindowsSDK_IncludePath macro missing

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

Just like the title says.

I go to project properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories  -> Macros>>

It's not in that list at all. The result is that VS cannot open Windows.h. How can I reset this macro to its default value (or set it at all)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That variable should be set by the installation of the Windows SDK. You likely just need to reinstall it (here is the link for 8.1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx).

Comment: It may be necessary to enable the C++ sub-components of the Windows SDK from Programs / apps (Windows SDK for Desktop C++ *processor-flavor* Apps) Also, the latest spells it out Windows Software Development Kit so searching "SDK" doesn't find it.